# Having trouble returning sums or differences of lines in a file python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that reads through the lines of a file and takes the sum of each line and prints it. It should skip lines that are only comments and are empty, but still count them when counting lines. The program should also be able to create variables from the file and use them. I currently have written the following code:

```
import sys

class BadStatement(Exception):
    #creates an exeption called BadStatement to be used in exception handling
    pass


def interpret_statements(filename):
    #opens a file, checks if it is a valid file, and runs the program
    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('specify filename')
    loop_lines(lines)

def loop_lines(lines):
    #goes through each line in the file prints the sums
    line_num=1
    line_sum=0
    for line in lines:
        line_sum=process_line(line)
        line_num=line_num+1
        if line_sum == None:
            print("Line %i: Invalid Statement" %(line_num))
        elif line_sum==0:
            continue
        else:
            print("Line %i: %s" %(line_num, line_sum))

def process_line(line):
    #takes each line in the file and preforms the calculations in order to get the value of each line
    num_list=line.split()
    variable_dict = {}
    add = True
    line_sum = 0
    try:
        for token in num_list:
            if token in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
                check_variable(variable_dict, token)
            elif token == '+':
                add = True
            elif token == '-':
                add = False
            elif token == '':
                continue
            else:
                raise BadStatement
            try:
                if add == True:
                    line_sum += float(token)
                elif add== False:
                    line_sum -= float(token)
            except ValueError:
                raise BadStatement
        return line_sum
    except BadStatement:
        return None

def check_variable(variable_dict, line):
    #checks to make sure all noninteger values are defined
    num_list1 = line.split()
    sum=0
    for each in num_list1:
        if num_list1[0] == "=":
            sum=num_list1[2]
            if num_list1[each.index-1] == '+':
                sum += float(each)
            elif num_list1[each.index-1] =='-':
                sum -=float(each)
        return sum
    variable_dict[num_list1[0]] = sum
    return variable_dict

def check_for_valid_number(line):
    number_valid = False
    while number_valid == False:
        try:
            process_line(line) 
            number_valid = True
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

A sample of a file is as follows:

```
# Test correct expression statements
14.4
    23.4 + -19 +   98223
10 - 34 + 12.66 - 28 - 3323.2 + 12
14.3 
92 - 13   # here is a comment after an expression
     34 + 13#and another comment

# Test correct assignment statements
x123 = 19278
    salary = 873 - 13 
time = -123.33 + salary - 123 + 23 + 0 + -123 - x123
x123 = x123 + 15  # reassign the value of x123

# And expression statements with variables
  x123
  14.4 - salary
  time + salary - 10 + x123

# Now test some invalid statements
1474 +
820.34 - junk  # junk has not been defined
2884 - -1293 + 399 t 266
23.8 - 203.3 +
+     123.2 - 23.2
2884.2 + 293 - 23.2 283.3 + +
34.8 273 - 12
x =
x = salary + time = 15
x$y34 = 17 
19 = 19   
1xyz = 123
```

The spaces and wacky formatting in the sample file are intentional. Currently, all lines are returned as an invalid statement. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This program is hard to fix, there are many errors (actually it's hard to find anything right, in my opinion). Just as an example consider the fery first non-comment line of the file:

```
x123 = 19278
```

the code is not going to be able to parse it: `num_list1` will be:

```
["x123", "=", "19278"]
```

and none of the `if` cases will work for first item, where `token` will be `"x123"`.

- `token in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` is false
- `token == '+'` is false
- `token == '-'` is false
- `token == ''` is false

so we get to `raise BadStatement`